# Protractor element caching

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I started to learn testing in Angular and have a little problem doing a serie of test in the same view.

I have a form with some inputs for customer data. I use it both for add new customer and edit an existing one.

So, firstly I test adding a new customer, then I click back, and click the first customer in a list (not the recently added). The data shows correctly in the view, but the test fails saying Expected 'new customer' to be 'customer 1'. Somehow element.name is caching the previous value.

Here is the test:

```
describe('Showing Customer data', function(){
    var customersMenu, homeMenu, firstListItem;

beforeEach(function() {
    customersMenu = element(by.css('.ion-person-stalker'));
    homeMenu = element(by.css('.ion-home'));
    firstListItem = element(by.css('.firstListItem'));
});

it('should create a new customer', function() {
    customersMenu.click();
    var newButton = element(by.css('.button-fab'));
    newButton.click();

    element(by.name('name')).sendKeys('new customer');
    [...] // The other fields...

    homeMenu.click();
});

it('should display correct customer data', function() {
    customersMenu.click();
    firstListItem.click();

    expect(element(by.name('name')).getAttribute('value')).toBe('customer 1');

    homeMenu.click();
});

});
```

Comment: Did you trying waiting for the element to appear on the screen and then check if the value is `customer 1` using `wait()` function ? thanks

Comment: I used browser.sleep(5000) to wait, with identical result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieve this.

**The problem**

The problem was I was navigating like an user will do. I was returning to home view and then going again to list view, and detail view. The problem with that is the previous elements remain, so element(by.name('name')) has two posible values: 'new customer' and 'customer 1'. I we use element() instead element.all(), Protractor will pick up the first element in array.

**The Solution**

Instead of returning home clicking the button in sidemenu, now I use   **browser.get('/')** to return to the root of app. It will clear DOM and seems is like you run the test as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are sending the keys "new customer" to the name field here:

```
element(by.name('name')).sendKeys('new customer');
```

should you not be sending "customer 1" and the value of the name field like this?

```
element(by.name('name')).sendKeys('customer 1');
```

then later when you get the value of the name field, this will be correct:

```
expect(element(by.name('name')).getAttribute('value')).toBe('customer 1');
```

Comment: I do 2 test, first I write customer data on an empty form, and send it to DB.

Then, in second test, I load another user from DB, and controller fills the form inputs with those data using ng-model. In the second test browser displays 'customer 1' in the form, but getting its value in test I got the previous value of that input.

If I swap test order, read customer from DB pass, but when try to sendKeys to input get 'element no visible' error...